# Netty systemd lazy initialization

Tags: java, sockets, netty, systemd

Is it possible to have netty lazy initialized via systemd/inetd, using inherited server socket channel?
We used this in our old Jetty based server, where Jetty would call Java's System.inheritedChannel() to get the socket created via systemd on lazy initializations.

I have searched a lot, and all I found is a Jira ticket that says it supposedly supports in version 4: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-309.

But this jira ticket has no example, and I couldn't find any documentation, nor anything on the source code, that could point me to how to achieve this in netty.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:
Just to make it more clear, what I want to know if is it possible to have my java application socket-activated by systemd, and then somehow pass the socket reference to netty.

EDIT 2:
Here is an approach suggested by Norman Mayer, but it actually fails with the exception below:

```
public class MyServerBootStrap {

  private ServiceContext ctx;
  private Config config;
  private Collection<Channel> channels;
  private Collection<Connector> connectors;

  public MyServerBootStrap(List<Connector> connectors) {
    this.ctx = ApplicationContext.getInstance();
    this.config = ctx.getMainConfig();
    this.connectors = connectors;
    this.channels = new ArrayList<>(connectors.size());
  }

  public void run(Connector connector) throws RuntimeException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(config.getInt("http_acceptor_threads", 0));
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(config.getIntError("http_server_threads"));

    final SocketAddress addr;
    final ChannelFactory<ServerChannel> channelFactory;
    if (connector.geEndpoint().isInherited()) {
      System.out.println(
          "Trying to bootstrap inherited channel: " + connector.geEndpoint().getDescription());
      ServerSocketChannel channel = (ServerSocketChannel) System.inheritedChannel();

      addr = channel.getLocalAddress();
      System.out.println("Channel localAddress(): " + addr);
      channelFactory = new MyChannelFactory(channel);
    } else {
      System.out.println(
          "Trying to bootstrap regular channel: " + connector.geEndpoint().getDescription());
      addr = connector.geEndpoint().getSocketAdress();
      channelFactory = new MyChannelFactory(null);
    }

    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b
        .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .localAddress(addr)
        .channelFactory(channelFactory)
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializerRouter(Collections.singletonList(connector)))
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

    if (config.contains("tcp_max_syn_backlog")) {
      b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, config.getIntError("tcp_max_syn_backlog"));
    }

    Channel serverChannel = b.bind().sync().channel();
    channels.add(serverChannel);
  }

  public void run() throws RuntimeException {
    try {
      for (Connector connector : connectors) {
        run(connector);
      }
      for (Channel channel : channels) {
        channel.closeFuture().sync();
      }
    } catch (Throwable exc) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Failed to start web-server", exc);
    } finally {
      // TODO: fix this
      // workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
      // bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
  }
}


class MyChannelFactory implements io.netty.channel.ChannelFactory<ServerChannel> {

  private ServerSocketChannel channel;

  public MyChannelFactory(ServerSocketChannel ch) {
    this.channel = ch;
  }

  @Override
  public ServerChannel newChannel() {
    if (channel == null) {
      return new NioServerSocketChannel();
    } else {
      return new NioServerSocketChannel(channel);
    }
  }

}
```

log:

```
 Trying to bootstrap inherited channel: public (tcp port: 8080)
 Channel localAddress(): /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start web-server
         at MyServerBootStrap.run(MyServerBootStrap.java:85)
         at MyServer.run(MyServer.java:61)
         at Main.start(Main.java:96)
         at Main.main(Main.java:165)
 Caused by: java.nio.channels.AlreadyBoundException
         at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:216)
         at sun.nio.ch.InheritedChannel$InheritedServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(InheritedChannel.java:92)
         at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128)
         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
         at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1338)
         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
         at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:999)
         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
         at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
         at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
         at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be possible.

The `NioServerSocketChannel` allows you to wrap an existing `Channel` via its constructor. So all you will need to do is to write your own `ChannelFactory` and use it with `ServerBootstrap` to ensure you create a `NioServerSocketChannel` that wraps it.

Another approach would be to not use `ServerBootstrap` at all but just call register etc with the manually created `NioServerSocketChannel` by yourself.

Comment: Hi Norman. The first solution looks beautiful, but in my case it won't help because my server will bind to multiple ports, but at most one will be inherited from systemd. Since ChannelFactory.newChannel() has no arguments, there's no way to decide if the channel to be returned is inherited or not. It's wierd to me that at the time of the Channel creatiion, we don't have the address to decide which kind of channel I can return. Any suggestions on how to tackle this approach for the scenario exposed?

Comment: Why not just use multiple ServerBootstrap instances ?

Comment: I thought that was kind of overkilling. But I just gave it a try, and the approach actually does not work. I'm updating the question with the code of my attempt.

Comment: Note that I had to add the localAddress to the serverBootsrap. The localaddress is mandatory at the time of binding, either on the bootstrap as I am doing, or as a parameter for the bind method.

Comment: If you use a pre-bound socket you should not call bind() but register() only

Comment: Great, changing to register works!! Thank you very much, Norman!